# jQuery parent children communication

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I writting plugin that **manipulate with checkboxes**.
And now i have some problem. After i **get JSON**, i want connect my children and parents.
Each children have **data-parent** with value this id.

Example child:     **{ "id": 4, "name": "name 1", "parent": 1}**,
Example parent:     **{ "id": 2, "name": "name 2", "parent": false }**

After rendering my first level (parents), i want append to parents, they childrens.
Please help, i dont know good practies to do this.

```
var $this = this.element; // (target to DOM element, in this context 'body')    
$.getJSON('js/ajax/data.json', function(data) {
var parentData = [];
var childrenData = [];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  if (data[i].parent == false) {
     parentData.push(
        '<div class="ra-megaselect-rubrics-level-one"><label>' +
        '<input type="checkbox" data-id="' + data[i].id + '">' +
        '<span>' + data[i].name + '</span>' +
        '</label></div> '
         )}
        else {
          childrenData.push(
            '<div class="ra-megaselect-rubrics-level-two"><label>' +
            '<input type="checkbox" data-id="' + data[i].id + '" data-parent="' + data[i].parent + '">' +
            '<span>' + data[i].name + '</span>' +
            '</label>'
           )}
         });

         $this.append(parentData);
        });
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and has typos - for example `$this` will probably not work. Did you mean `$(this)`? The function passed as second argument to `$.each` is missing a bunch of closing braces. It's hard to understand what the problem is here, and the fact that this question is missing a question doesnt make it easier. Can you try to pin down the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I fix it. Ready. It's part of my plugin code.
I post init method from plugin.

Comment: No problem, thanks. But could you tell us what exactly the problem is? Is there an error? Is there something you don't understand?

Comment: Yeah, i dont understand how i can connect children and parent. I want find best practies.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is known as a Closure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29

What you did is really common code. The part that is a bad practice is having the HTML bomb droped has a string in the middle of the javascript.

For maintainability you should probably turn your "children" and "parents" into objects, which store a reference to their respective node, and provide you with a bunch of utility functions, so that you can directly manipulate them. [Take a look here](http://franciscomsferreira.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-write-maintainable-javascript-or.html)

Comment: @KirillKaysarov check the second link